# IMU adafruit BNO055 driver for ros2

Tags: ros2, imu, raspberry-pi, arduino#ros#raspberry

I hope you're all having a great day!

I'm here with a couple of questions regarding IMUs and their drivers:

1. For those familiar with the Adafruit BNO055 IMU connected to an Arduino Uno, which specific driver is typically used for interfacing with this setup?
2. Additionally, I'm curious if there's a driver available that facilitates the transfer of IMU data via serial communication from an Arduino Uno to a Raspberry Pi.

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!"

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the Adafruit BNO055 driver you are looking for but in regards to your second question:

> Additionally, I'm curious if there's a driver available that facilitates the transfer of IMU data via serial communication from an Arduino Uno to a Raspberry Pi.

The current way of using ROS 2 with microcontrollers such as the Arduino is to use [micro-ROS](https://micro.ros.org/). However, if you are only using your Arduino to read the BNO055, I would recommend you connect your IMU directly to your Raspberry Pi since it [has i2c](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c).